# Python 2.4: Get the output of system commands into a non-quoted string

Tags: python, shell, command, psql

I want to write the output of a psql-command into an integer variable that I can use with some "if x larger than 0" statement in python, but I cannot get the value only.

My environment is limited. I cannot import the psycopg(2) and I cannot update so I have to work with the given commands of python 2.4.

See the following:

```
>>> os.popen('psql -d database -U datareader -t -A -c "select count(*) from mails"').read()
'151\n'
```

or

```
>>> commands.getoutput('psql -d database -U datareader -t -A -c "select count(*) from mails"')
'151'
```

Both outputs are at least singlequoted strings and I don't know how to use them as integers.

Another way is older `os.system`:

```
>>> os.system('psql -U database -d datareader -t -A -c "select count(*) from mails"')
151
0
```

No quotes, but the output of the command is the exit code and the commands output. Putting this into a variable puts only the exit code in, not the command output.

The latter one could go with a workaround by writing the output with appended into a file. This however, I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

The output from an external command is **always** going to be a string. Convert it to an integer manually:

```
output = commands.getoutput('psql -d database -U datareader -t -A -c "select count(*) from mails"')
count = int(output)
```